# Existence of translations of a set with certain property

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This fact was used in a book on Fourier analysis I'm reading

> Given $A \subset [0,1]$ there exists translates $(A_k) \subset [0,1]$ of $A$ such that $$|\cap_{k=1}^n A_k| \leq \frac{e}{2} |A|^n,$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Where $|\cdot|$ denotes the Lebesgue measure and by translation I mean a set of the form $A + x$ for some $x \in [0,1]$ where the values are modolu 1.

I have stared at it for quite some time but I can't figure out why this would hold. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to prove this statement? All thoughts are welcome.

Comment: You wrote "translates $(A_k) \in [0,1]$ of $A$". I think it is a typo.  Translates of $A$ should be subsets of $[0,1]$.

Comment: $e$ is the Euler number (Napier constant)?

Comment: Which book? On what page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course $A$ is assumed measurable.  I will prove this for $e=2$, using mathematical induction.

Suppose you have $A_k$ for $k = 1 \ldots n$, and let $B = \bigcap_{k=1}^n A_k$.  Thus
$|B| \le  |A|^n$.
Now $|B \cap (A + x)| = \int_0^1 \chi_B(s) \chi_{A+x}(s)\; ds$, where $\chi_S$ is the indicator function of set $S$.   By Fubini,

$$\int_0^1 |B \cap (A+x)|\; dx = \int_0^1 \chi_B(s) \int_0^1 \chi_{A+x}\; dx \; ds = |A| |B|$$
Since this says the average of $|B \cap (A+x)|$ is $|A||B|$, there must be some $x$ such that $|B \cap (A+x)| \le |A| |B|$.  Take $A_{n+1} = A + x$ for such $x$, and we have $\left|\bigcap_{k=1}^{n+1} A_k\right| \le |A|^{n+1}$.